# How do I disconnect unmapped Network Login?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I have connected to a network shared folder but I haven't mapped it to any drive. Now I want to disconnect from that shared location without restarting my PC. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16196/how-to-disconnect-non-mapped-unc-path-drives-in-windows/) should help you with that.

> Open up a command prompt, and then type in the following:
>
> net use
>
> This will give you a list of the connected drives, including the ones
>   that aren’t actually mapped to a drive letter. To disconnect one of
>   the connections, you can use the following command:
>
> net use /delete \server\sharename
>
> For example, in this instance we’d disconnect like so:
>
> net use /delete \192.168.1.205\root$

Comment: Well, I tried it but I still able to open that network folder though there is no entry of that path in net view if I try to access it again within 30 seconds. Can I call it a bug of Microsoft? And one more thing when I try to open a network folder which is not accessible to me, Net Use also managed that entry. why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by you can still open the folder.  The command only disconnects from the resource, it won't stop you from reopening the connection.  And when you say "mangled" what do you mean?